# Sequelize not creating Junction tables for many-to-many relationships

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I don't see the junction tables getting created for my code below (for UserEvents as:Attendees). When I try to add 'Attendee' to an Event using event.setAttendees([user]), it sets the EventId on the user table (thus making it a one-to-many relationship)

During sync logging, no tables with 'userevents' related name gets created

```
var User = db.import(__dirname + '/user');
var Event = db.import(__dirname + '/event');

Event.hasMany(User, { as: 'Attendees'});
User.hasMany(Event);

db.sync({logging: console.log}).success(function() {
  logger.info('DB Initialization successful!');
  createDefaultData()
}).error(function(err) {
  logger.error('DB Initialization failed!', err);
});

var createDefaultData = function() {

  User.create({email:"test@test.com", firstName: "tolga", lastName: "ekmen", password: "qwer", location: "13424"});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an alias (`{ as: 'Attendees'}`) you have to tell sequelize that you want a join table, by specifying `through`, which can either be a string or a model:

```
Event.hasMany(User, { as: 'Attendees', through: 'user_events' });
User.hasMany(Event, { , through: 'user_events' });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the documentation fails at that since in many-to-many they use the example and do it wrong.. Thanks!

Comment: We should get that fixed! Could you point me to the specific page / line? Or open an issue at http://github.com/sequelize/doc?